# Is there any way to mark a TODO as important or any other flag?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I'm new to Android Studio and working on a pretty complex application. There is lots of TODOs(TODO in comments) in the source code.
I wonder if there is any markup or any other tools to prioritize TODOs in source code?
For example:

```
//TODO: Important
//TODO: Urgent
```

, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any markup or any other tools to prioritize
>   TODOs in source code

1) Android studio takes care of the highlighting to make it stand out, to  change it navigate to
 ***Settings->Editor->inspections change sevirity***

2) you can use **`// fixme`**,to show higher priority.

Comment: I use android studio 2.0, I saw the **Settings->Editor->TODO** but no inspections change sevirity. In severity I can change TODO severity and all TODOs will be affected. Is it right?

Comment: yes, for any future projects also this setting will be applied

Comment: Thanks, I got the Idea, using this feature and combination with filters we can achieve the prioritized to-do s. Thank you so much. Solved!

Comment: sure, happy coding